# Find difference between max and second max, grouped by columns in MySql (8.0.13), without using the order by and limit clause

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I  have a table with the columns ID, ad_id, amount_time, which shows the ID of users, the ad that they saw, and how much time they seen it. Here is an example of the data:

```
table name: ads

ID | ad_id | amount_time
 1      2        600            
 1      3        300
 3      1        400
 1      3        100
 1      1        700
```

We want the result to show the difference between max and 2nd max of amount_time, grouped by ID and ad_id

So the result is

```
ID |ad_id | diff_amount_time
 1    3      200
```

I can get the max and second_max of the total table by executing:

```
select
(SELECT MAX(amount_time) FROM ads) maxtime,
(SELECT MAX(amount_time) FROM ads
WHERE amount_time NOT IN (SELECT MAX(amount_time) FROM ads )) as 
second_max_time
```

However, I am having trouble incorporating the group by clause in order to get my result. I know there's a way to incorporate `order by` and `limit 2` to get the max and and second max, but this is computationally expensive and want to know if there is another solution without ordering the amount_time column.

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: Just edited it in the title. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: How do you get `200`?

Comment: The only `ID` and `ad_id` combination that appears twice is when `ID = 1` and `ad_id = 3`. The max amount and second max amount for these are `300` and `100`. So the difference between them is `200`

Comment: You do not want to show the groups when there is no second highest value ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, yes that is true.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, thanks for the answer, have a question. So there really isn't a way to get away from `order by`? Is there a way to include a clause like `select max(amount_time) from ads where amount_time < (select max(amount_time) from ads)` along with the `partition by` statement? Or is there really not a performance issue if you use `order by` with the window function?

Comment: @KevinSun `MAX()` function will also do a full table scan if there is no indexing. Same thing is applicable for `ORDER BY`.  MySQL has significantly optimized usage of `ORDER BY`. Would recommend you to read this article: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Infact, problem with your approach would be usage of multiple subqueries, and multiple MAX() function calls. This will be *much* more inefficient. You can analyze `EXPLAIN` statement results for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0.2+, simplest *and possibly most performant* way would be to use [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html).

We will use [`Row_Number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) function, which will determine the row number values within a combination of `ID` and `ad_id`. Row number will be based on descending order `amount_time` value. So the highest `amount_time` value will have row number of 1, and the second highest would have row number of 2.

Now, we will use this result-set as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and aggregate (`GROUP BY`) on `ID` and `ad_id`. We can use conditional [`CASE .. WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expressions, to determine the difference between the highest and second highest value within every group.

```
SELECT
  dt.ID, 
  dt.ad_id, 
  (MAX(CASE WHEN dt.row_no = 1 THEN dt.amount_time END) - 
  MAX(CASE WHEN dt.row_no = 2 THEN dt.amount_time END)) AS diff_amount_time
FROM 
(
 SELECT 
   ID, 
   ad_id, 
   amount_time, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(ID, '-', ad_id)
                      ORDER BY amount_desc) AS row_no
 FROM ads 
) AS dt 
GROUP BY dt.ID, dt.ad_id 
-- to remove cases where there is no second highest
-- when there is no second highest amount, then the difference will be null
-- because 5 - null = null
HAVING diff_amount_time IS NOT NULL
```